# Set critical process Ruby FFI

Tags: ruby, winapi, ffi

I am new to *Windows API* programming and was playing with *Ruby FFI* gem.
I was curious about creating critical process, and here is the code I have.
The problem is, that I keep getting *Nope* message, which means process was not set as critical. Can't figure out what's wrong here
Thanks in advance

```
require 'ffi'

module Win
    extend FFI::Library
    ffi_lib 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'
    ffi_convention :stdcall

    attach_function :RtlSetProcessIsCritical, [:int, :int, :int], :void
end

module Kernel
    extend FFI::Library
    ffi_lib 'kernel32'
    ffi_convention :stdcall

    attach_function :GetCurrentProcess, [], :pointer
    attach_function :IsProcessCritical, [:pointer, :pointer], :int
end

begin 
    ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new :bool, 1
    Win.RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0)

    cprcs = Kernel.GetCurrentProcess()
    Win.IsProcessCritical(cprcs, ptr)

    if ptr.get(:bool, 0) then
        puts "Critical"
    else
        puts "Nope."
    end
rescue => e
    puts e
ensure
    Win.RtlSetProcessIsCritical(0, 0, 0)
end
```

Comment: You need to have at least debug privileges (possibly more) to make a process a critical process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ["Protecting" Your Process with `RtlSetProcessIsCritical`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43405/Protecting-Your-Process-with-RtlSetProcessIsCriti):

> Note: The use of this function requires the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege in the calling process. This can easily be obtained using [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202(VS.85).aspx)